# Angular Running Errors

Tags: angular

When I am Running my project, the[Angular Server Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2xf6.jpg) project has some errors. several times I reinstall Node Module and change The Code. but not responded. also, I'm not using loops. didn't understand How to Fix this problem. I think it is a lap spaces issue. but I tried another laptop also. but didn't work.

Comment: No, it is not laptop space issue... it is issue of imports..

Comment: Try deleting `node_modules`, `dist`, and `.angular` if they are there, then reinstall. Seems to fix the issue according to this thread: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/17106. Read that for other possible solutions.

Answer (score -1):

This issue comes when we do mistakes while importing modules.
I think that you are importing modules circularly like for an example -

**Module A is importing module B and vice-versa also true.**
So this will create a chain and in this case call stack exceeded error will occur..

Look into imports carefully and imports only dependent modules.

Let me know if i can help you further in this .

It will be good if you can paste a stackblitz link for the same so that i can take a look into the imports if it won't solve you.

Thanks.